# If f is injective can you prove this relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given that f maps E to F and A is a subset of E,  prove that if f is injective then f^-1(f(A)) is a subset of A.

Actually, im good at performing similar proofs, but i didn't understand why should f be injective? I proved it without using this given and didn't know how to benefit from it.
Please help me cz i have an exam.
Thanks :)

Comment: If $f$ is not injective then there might be $a,b$ with $a\in A$, $b\notin A$ and $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: But if f(x) ∈ f(A) then for sure x ∈ A.  Can we consider f(x) ∈ f(A) but x ∉ A ? Is that true even if f is not injective??

Comment: to prove that a set B is a subset of C, take an element of B and show it is in C.

Comment: No, $f(x)\in f(A)$ does not imply that $x\in A$ (unless $f$ is injective).  Take $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=x^2$, $A=\{2\}$.  Then $f(A) = \{4\}$.  But $f(-2)=4$ so $f(-2)\in f(A)$ even though $-2\notin A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be in $f^{-1}(f(A))$.

$x\in f^{-1}(f(A)) \implies$

$f(x) \in f(A) \implies$

$\exists a \in A : f(x)=f(a)$.

$f(x)=f(a)$ and $f$ injective $ \implies$

$x=a$

$x=a$ and $a\in A \implies x\in A$

each $x$ of $f^{-1}(f(A))$ is in $A$.

thus

$$f^{-1}(f(A)) \subset A$$

Comment: Why should I let a ∈ A ? Why can't I put x instead ?

Comment: $f(A)$ contains, by definition, only images of the elements of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $x\in f^{-1}(f(A))$. Then $f(x)\in f(A)$. Hence there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(x)=f(a)$. Injectivity of $f$ then implies that $x=a$. In particular, $x\in A$. Hence, $f^{-1}(f(A))\subset A$.

To show that injectivity is really needed, consider for instance the non-injective function
$$f:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow\{a,b,c\}: \begin{cases} a\mapsto a\newline b\mapsto a\newline c\mapsto a \end{cases}.$$
If we take $A=\{a\}$, then $f^{-1}(f(A))=f^{-1}(\{a\})=\{a,b,c\}$ which is not a subset of $A$.

Comment: Why should I let a ∈ A ? Why can't I put x instead ?

Comment: The equation $f(x)\in f(A)$ by itself does not necessarily imply that $x\in A$. For instance, in the example I gave we have $f(c)\in f(\{a\})$, though $c\notin \{a\}$. All you can really say is that there exists some $a\in A$ such that $f(x)=f(a)$.

Comment: Oh i got it. Thank you